# How can I add tasks from a PHP google app engine app to a pull queue?

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine, task-queue, pull-queue

I am trying to add tasks to a pull queue from a PHP based GAE app.As of right now, pull queues do not support PHP and therefore I was hoping someone could tell me how to solve this issue. So far, I have tried the following but failed:

1) **Use a TASK API.**:

> Got a "403 error:not allowed to make this API call".

This API can only be called from outside GAE.

2) **Used Shell_exec, exec,passthru and system command within PHP** to execute a python script to add task to pull queue: got a warning

> Warning: exec() has been disabled for security reasons in
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~apigraymatics/1.390159863933635324/public/pull/dummy1.php
>   on line 9

Is there any other way to go about this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try my (alpha) library which provides pull queue support for PHP  on AppEngine.

https://github.com/tomwalder/php-appengine-pull-queue

Enjoy!